# two tables, one chart (x-axis is time)

Tags: macos, numbers

I have two tables such as

```
            Var_A   Var_B
5. Jan 2017 33.3    2.22
5. Jun 2017 44.44   3.33

            Var_A   Var_B
5. Feb 2016 22.2    5.55
5. Jul 2016 27.2    4.44
```

and I would like to plot them in one plot (scatter, line) that shows both variables Var_A and Var_B on the y-axis and one continuous time axis (x-axis).

How close can I get to this with Numbers v 4.3 on macOS?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to clean up the table first?

Comment: I'm with @patrix - you could make up a shadow table to get all the data in one place and then chart it - seems like a lot of work but doable if you need this. I wonder if javascript automation could help automate this shadow table creation...

Comment: reasons are many... different data files, for example... yes, I could clean up beforehand, but difficult, also different lengths of entries for different variables (in reality there are more than two). -- what is a shadow table?